# Entity Framework 7 Many To Many without unnecessary classes and extraneous navigation properies

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The tinterweb (including stackoverflow) has so many old articles on this issue and EF has evolved significantly over recent years.

Hence I'm trying to establish the definitive answer to this problem hopefully with expert advice including the current state of EF core (version 7).

The context is an existing SQL Server where Table and Column naming standards are immutable and I'm trying to map on an existing set of tables.  I will use generic terms to avoid distraction.

Starting with a highly referenced table/entity:

```cs
public class Token
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Token_ID")]
    public int TokenId {get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a consumer of one or more Tokens:

```cs
public class ConsumerA
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ConsumerA_ID")]
    public int ConsumerAId {get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set;}

    public List<Tokens>? Tokens {get; set;}
}
```

Note that this consumer does not own the Tokens referenced, its not a parent/child relationship.  Tokens exist on their own and there are other consumers of tokens also referencing the Token table.

The sql server has a table representing the many to many join:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ConsumerA_Tokens
(
    ConsumerA_ID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_ConsumerA_Tokens_ConsumerA
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ConsumerA (ConsumerA_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    , Token_ID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_ConsumerA_Tokens_Token
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Token (Token_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    , CONSTRAINT PK_ConsumerA_Tokens PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ConsumerA_ID, Token_ID)
)
```

So **the question is this**.  What do I need to include in my `OnModelCreating` override to describe the many to many relationship without adding additional properties and classes to my models that I have no need of in code?

This my starting point:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ConsumerA>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Tokens)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity("ConsumerA_Tokens");
```

However when creating a new ConsumerA and assigning a set of Tokens (retrieved via EF) on save I get a SQL error

```
Invalid column name 'ConsumerAId'. Invalid column name 'TokensTokenId'.
```

Clearly I need a way to inform EF of the column names to used via `UsingEntity` but it is just so opaque and as mentioned the tinterweb is full of mis-direction.

**Edit:**

Here is a what I currently need to do to make my code work but it breaks the conditions I have set for myself

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ConsumerA>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Tokens)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity<ConsumerATokens>();
```

This breaks my conditions because to make this work I'm required to create the following class which I don't actually need anywhere else in my code:

```cs
[Table("ConsumerA_Tokens")]
public class ConsumerATokens
{
    [Column("ConsumerA_ID")]
    public int ConsumerAId { get; set; }

    [Column("Token_ID")]
    public int TokenId { get; set; }

    public ConsumerA? ConsumerA { get; set; }
    public Token? Token { get; set; }
}
```

This at least avoids horrible naviagition properties in the Token class.  However since this class merely exists to describe schema/metadata to the EF model, it seems to me that there ought to be a way to do this against the `modelBulider`.

Comment: Note that "the definitive answer" today will be part of the old answers soon ;). Did you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) to see which options there are? Only if `Token` has a collection property for `ConsumerA`s then EF will do this w/o any configuration code.

Comment: @GertArnold yeah I read that.  So I have ConsumerB, ConsumerC, ConsumerD ... and my token class has to define all these collections for things to work.  There has to be a better way than this?  Why should Token class have any clue about the multitude of potential referrers it has?    The goal of the question (as described in the title) is can these ugly reverse referee navigation properties be avoided?

Comment: Sure, it's not necessary (and undesirable by all means) for `Token` to have all these properties, but then configuring code is inevitable. Can't help it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not well documented, but you can define the "skip navigation" using "UsingEntity(...)". I'll try to take something I have and adapt to your example.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ConsumerA>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Tokens)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity(
        "ConsumerATokens", //arbitrary name
            r => r.HasOne(typeof(Token))
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("TokenId") //arbitrary prop name 1
                .HasPrincipalKey("Token_ID"),
            l => l.HasOne(typeof(ConsumerA))
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("ConsumerAId") //arbitrary prop name 2
                .HasPrincipalKey("ConsumerA_ID"),
            j =>
            {
                j.ToTable("ConsumerA_Tokens");
                j.Property<int>("TokenId").HasColumnName("Token_ID"); //matches arbitrary prop name 1
                j.Property<int>("ConsumerAId").HasColumnName("ConsumerA_ID"); //matches arbitrary prop name 2
            });
```

[Partial documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)